# can we see Estimote analytics just by connecting to estimote beacons and not actually stick them on a wall?

Tags: ibeacon, beacon, estimote

Can we see analytics just by connecting to beacons ( beacons who are not actually STICK to the walls ) through estimote app ?

Due to pandemic in India it is not possible  to go to the office now . I have a development kit of proximity beacons  and I need to develop a simple project out of it.
So should i travel and  bring that kit to home  and develop an app using some already available templates and later on return it to the office so that once we resume after 5-6 months  we can stick them to the wall and play around it.

Please let me know, I have read every article but can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to bring the kit home, enable the beacons so they are transmitting (which means the battery  will start being used), register them with Estimote, and then use a mobile phone in the vicinity of the beacons with an app running the Estimote SDK.  You may install the beacons in their permanent location at a later time.

Comment: Thanks David Young for quick response. so helpful!